# Why does Hibernate remove all elements in a set if i remove all elements of another set in the same class?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I have two classes: Book and Member. In the Member class there are two HashSet which store Books: `borrowedBooks` and `returnedBooks`.

When I remove one Book from `borrowedBooks` and put it into `returnedBook`, Hibernate will do that without a problem for all except for the last element in `borrowedBooks`. However, if i remove the last element in `borrowedBooks` Hibernate also removes all of the Books in `returnedBook`. So, at the end of scenario there are no Books in `borrowedBooks`, but there are also no Books in `returnedBooks`.

For example:

```
1) borrowedBooks: a, b, c
1) returnedBooks:
---
2) borrowedBooks: a, b
2) returnedBooks: c
---
3) borrowedBooks: a
3) returnedBooks: b, c
---
4) borrowedBooks: -
4) returnedBooks: -
```

That's really not understandable!  Why does this happen? Thanks a lot for your help!
Here are my classes:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

@Id
@TableGenerator(...)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "Book_Barcode")
private long barcode;
private long isbn=0;
private String bookTitle="";
// some other fields

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) (barcode ^ (barcode >>> 32));
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Book other = (Book) obj;
    if (barcode != other.barcode)
        return false;
    return true;
}

}



@Entity
public class Member {

@Id
@TableGenerator(...)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "Member_Id")
private int id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //please ignore FetchType!
private Set<Book> returnedBooks = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Book> borrowedBooks = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Book> renewedBooks = new HashSet<>();
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public class MemberDAOImpl implements MemberDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
@Transactional
public void borrowBook(Member member, Book book) {
    if (book.getStatus().equals("Available") && 
        book.getAvailableAmount() > 0) {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        book.setBorrowedDate(new Date());
        book.setAvailableAmount(book.getAvailableAmount() - 1);
        book.setStatus("Borrowed");

        Member newMember = currentSession.find(Member.class, member.getId());
        newMember.getBorrowedBooks().add(book);
    } 
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void returnBook(Member member, Book book) {
    if (book.getStatus().equals("Borrowed")) {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Member newMember = currentSession.find(Member.class, member.getId());
        newMember.getReturnedBooks().add(book);
        newMember.getBorrowedBooks().remove(book);

        book.setBorrowedDate(null);
        book.setAvailableAmount(book.getAvailableAmount() + 1);
        book.setStatus("Available");
        book.setRenewedTimes(0);
    } 
}
}
```

---

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/member")
public class MemberController {

static Member member;

@Autowired
private MemberService memberService;

@Autowired
private BookService bookService;

@GetMapping("/bookBorrow")
public String bookBorrow(@RequestParam("barcode") long barcode, Model model) {
    Book book = bookService.searchBookByBarcode(barcode);
    memberService.borrowBook(member, book);
    model.addAttribute("booksList", member.getBorrowedBooks());
    model.addAttribute("member", member);
    return "member-specific-home-page";
}

@GetMapping("/bookReturn")
public String bookReturn(@RequestParam("barcode") long barcode, Model model) {
    Book book = bookService.searchBookByBarcode(barcode);
    memberService.returnBook(member, book);
    model.addAttribute("booksList", member.getReturnedBooks());
    model.addAttribute("member", member);
    return "member-specific-home-page";
}


}
```

So, I believe there is no problem in `public void borrowBook(...)`.
Is there something wrong in `public void returnBook(...)`?
I spent a lot of time but i could not find a way... Thanks in advance!

================================
There is something wrong with Hibernate!
For example: if i have 3 books in borrowedBooks set and than if i try to return them: so remove from borrowedBooks and put in returnedBook.

FIRST RETURN:

Hibernate: **update Book** set amount=?, availableAmount=?, bookTitle=?, borrowedDate=?, description=?, editedDate=?, edition=?, isbn=?, issuedDate=?, language=?, page=?, price=?, publisher=?, registrationDate=?, renewedDate=?, renewedTimes=?, status=? where barcode=?

Hibernate: **insert into Member_Book** (Member_id, returnedBooks_barcode) values (?, ?)

Hibernate: **delete from Member_Book** where Member_id=? and borrowedBooks_barcode=?

SECOND RETURN:

Hibernate: **update Book** set amount=?, availableAmount=?, bookTitle=?, borrowedDate=?, description=?, editedDate=?, edition=?, isbn=?, issuedDate=?, language=?, page=?, price=?, publisher=?, registrationDate=?, renewedDate=?, renewedTimes=?, status=? where barcode=?

Hibernate: **insert into Member_Book** (Member_id, returnedBooks_barcode) values (?, ?)

Hibernate: **delete from Member_Book** where Member_id=? and borrowedBooks_barcode=?

THIRD RETURN:

Hibernate: **update Book** set amount=?, availableAmount=?, bookTitle=?, borrowedDate=?, description=?, editedDate=?, edition=?, isbn=?, issuedDate=?, language=?, page=?, price=?, publisher=?, registrationDate=?, renewedDate=?, renewedTimes=?, status=? where barcode=?

Hibernate: **insert into Member_Book** (Member_id, returnedBooks_barcode) values (?, ?)

Hibernate: **delete from Member_Book** where Member_id=?

PLEASE LOOK AT THE "LAST" DELETE OPERATION: **delete from Member_Book where Member_id=?**
WHY JUST "where Member_id=?" ???

Comment: Those Eager fetch types will kill you sooner or later.

Comment: I know but lets ignore them. There is another big problem..

Comment: Could you add the code that invokes repository methods?

Comment: @ErikLucio i added

Comment: Check the data of this variable 'static Member member;' because in the Repository you are modifying a new instance of Member. Then, the Controller does not have the updated Member data.

Comment: I saw something wrong with Hibernate!!! Please look again my edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the right answer, but two things stand of in your code :

### Session / Transacitonal boundaries

Your controler is not transactionnal (which is OK).

```
@GetMapping("/bookBorrow")
public String bookBorrow(@RequestParam("barcode") long barcode, Model model) {
    Book book = bookService.searchBookByBarcode(barcode);
    memberService.returnBook(member, book);
    //...
```

Your `memberService.returnBook()` is :

```
@Transactional
public void returnBook(Member member, Book book) {
```

So we can infer that for a single HTTP request (call to your controler), there is one hibernate session opened for `bookService.searchBook...`, and *another one* opened in `memberService.returnBook`.

When you have two hibernate sessions sharing the same entities, "funny" things happen. You should not use the `book` instance got from the `bookService` inside the `memeberService`, at least not without reattaching it.

(Well actually my advice would be to have your whole controler dispatch to a single transaction and hibernate session, not two, and not have to worry about stuff like that).

What does "funny" mean ? The main issue is that hibernate guarantees you that, in a single session, any handle it gives you to a persistent object (book, member), is the same, as in : they are `==`. If you are in a single session, then `bookService.load(id) == bookService.load(id)`. This is not the case in your current controler implementation, so the objects may or may not be the same.

Which is kind of probelmatic, because... issue 2

### HashCode / Equals design

Your hashCode and equals are not aligned with a reasonnable intent. Basically your book `hashCode` is a hash of the barCode. And your equals is an `==` comparison on the barCode. I bet you meant `.equals()`, but you wrote "==".

So unless two books have the same barcode String instance (highly unlikely), they are never equal.

### So what happens ?

Well, you fetch a book in a hibernate session, you get back an instance that I will call Book@1, with a barcode "123" which is a String instance that I will call String@1.

Then you close the hibernate session, and you enter another one.

In this session, you load a Member, Member@1, which has a set of books, that hibernates load, but you are in a new Session. So hibernate loads a new book instance each time, and you end up with Book instance Book@2, with barcode "123" which is String@2 (the strings hold the same chars, they are `.equals`, but they are not `==`).

So you remove Book@1 from the Member@1's book set. What does the implementation do ? It looks if Book@2 and Book@1 are the same. `.hashcode()` wise, they are. `.equals()` wise ? They are not. The @Book1 is not @Book2 and is not equal to it, so it is not removed.

Another consequence, is that whatever you do to Book@1 is not tracked by hibernate, because the session that created Book@1 is closed. So it actually becomes a gray area : what if you add Book@1 to Member@1. How could hibernate know that it actually not is a new book that you just created ? Should it know it at all ?

### Now what ?

Fix your equals. It's good that you have a "natural key" for books, and that you use it, but you probably used `==` where you should have used `.equals()`

Have proper transaction boundaries. Hibernate will work a lot better if you do not spend time creating situations where you have different instances of the same entity.

User proper naming : what you call MemberDAO is not a DAO. A DAO accesses and stores objects in accordance to query patterns. Here, your MemberDAO manipulates different entities in accordance to business logic (e.g. if I give a book back, increment an availability counter). This is not a DAO's job, it is a service's job. Proper naming will usually help you set proper transaction boundaries, which will help proper session demarcation. (E.g. it is usually suspicious to have @Transactionnal on an DAO implementation, unless you "cut corners". It happens, if you write a really simple CRUD service and you want to save time, but when business logic sneaks in, this is a code smell to have a @Transactionnal DAO).

And finally, use a step by step debugger. Hibernate does not usually send SQL that does not match the state of you object's instances.